# How to copy a column value to other column of same database table whenever a new record is inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, triggers

I have the following database table:

```
Book {Id(primary Key), Name, TotalNoOfCopies, NoOfCopiesAvailable}
```

I want that whenever a new record/row is inserted the column NoOfCopiesAvailabe contains the same value as in column TotalNoOfCopies.
I tried using the following successful trigger:

```
for insert
as declare @id nvarchar(10),@name varchar(50),@author varchar(40),@totalNoOfCopies tinyint, @availableNoOfCOpies tinyint;
select @id=i.Id from inserted i;
select @name=i.Name from inserted i;
select @author=i.Author from inserted i;
select @totalNoOfCopies=i.TotalNoOfCopies from inserted i;
select @availableNoOfCopies=i.TotalNoOfCopies from inserted i;
delete from Book where Id=@id;
insert into Book values(@id,@name,@author,@totalNoOfCopies,@availableNoOfCOpies);
```

But it performs 3 transactions:
1.For inserting a new record
2.For deleting that new record
3.For inserting the new record that has NoOfCopiesAvailable=TotalNoOfCopies

For example:

```
Insert into Book values('123','Book','Author',5,null)
```

Messages:
1 row(s) affected
1 row(s) affected
1 row(s) affected
I was wondering if there is any way of doing it in a single transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Book_i ON Book
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Book (
        Id,
        Name,
        TotalNoOfCopies, 
        NoOfCopiesAvailable
    ) SELECT
        Id,
        Name,
        TotalNoOfCopies,
        TotalNoOfCopies
    ) FROM
        INSERTED
END
GO
```

It is clear an elegant.

Comment: Thank you v.much. It worked. But still there are two transactions. Is there any way that in a single insert command this can be achieved. Any other way than using a trigger? Thank you.

Comment: It seems you misunderstanding transactions. This is a transaction that affects 2 operations. To ensure single transaction you should place code into `begin transaction` and `commit` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather fix the table design and have NumberOfCopiesSold instead,  which can be 0 by default.